# Is it possible to autogenerate Swagger yaml from the routes available in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yaml, swagger

REST Api services is available in Node.js express app along with routes are specified properly. I am planning to use node.js to auto generate the swagger YAML Open API specification. Writing a swagger YAML manually is tough if you have more endpoints and the intention to add more endpoints will need to  update everywhere.

Example:  Consider a REST API services contains two basic endpoints and specified in the following YAML

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "0.0.1"
  title: Hello World App
# during dev, should point to your local machine
host: localhost:10010
# basePath prefixes all resource paths 
basePath: /
# 
schemes:
  # tip: remove http to make production-grade
  - http
  - https
# format of bodies a client can send (Content-Type)
consumes:
  - application/json
# format of the responses to the client (Accepts)
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /hello:
    # binds a127 app logic to a route
    x-swagger-router-controller: hello_world
    get:
      description: Returns 'Hello' to the caller
      # used as the method name of the controller
      operationId: hello
      parameters:
        - name: name
          in: query
          description: The name of the person to whom to say hello
          required: false
          type: string
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Success
          schema:
            # a pointer to a definition
            $ref: "#/definitions/HelloWorldResponse"
        # responses may fall through to errors
        default:
          description: Error
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"
  /try:
    x-swagger-router-controller: hello_world
    get:
      description: Returns 'Try' to the caller
      operationId: try
      parameters:
        - name: name
          in: query
          description: The content to try
          required: false
          type: string
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Success
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/HelloWorldResponse"
        default:
          description: Error
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"
  /swagger:
    x-swagger-pipe: swagger_raw
# complex objects have schema definitions
definitions:
  HelloWorldResponse:
    required:
      - message
    properties:
      message:
        type: string
  ErrorResponse:
    required:
      - message
    properties:
      message:
        type: string
```

My doubt is how can i generate this YAML in Node.js? Is there any specific NPM package or any swagger module available to generate this kind of YAML or writing code on own is preferable?

Trying to analyze the better way to do this. I appreciate all suggestions and thanks in advance!